# How to handle Delete request exception

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, retrofit

I have a delete request that works fine, but when I make subsequent delete calls to an item that has already been deleted in the API, I get an Exception, and the app crashes. I tried handling the error using Try/Catch with different exceptions eg(HttpException, IOException, etc) to prevent the app from crashing but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private fun deleteFavourite(
    favourite: GetFavourite?,
    viewModel: WallpapersSharedViewModel
) {
    //handling 404 error in case of subsequent Delete request
    try {
        if (favourite != null && !favourite.isEmpty()) {
            val favouriteId = favourite.get(0).id
            viewModel.deleteFavourite(favouriteId)
            Log.i("hiiiiyaa", "deleted${favouriteId}")
        }
    }
    catch (e: HttpException){
        Log.i("hiiiiyaa", "cannot find item to delete in the Api")
    }
}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.catexplorer, PID: 28492
    retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 
        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@fc41e38, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Comment: Are some of the queued delete calls made after your activity is no longer in focus?

Comment: No i dont think they are made when the activity is no longer on focus

Comment: What is the full type of the HttpException you are trying to catch?

Comment: @TheLibrarian I'm not sure what u mean by full type.. but it's a delete request  and its not returning anything

Comment: What HttpException do you import? My point was if you are catching `HttpException` from retrofit  (`retrofit2.HttpException) or from somewhere else.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Oh yes, I'm catching  it from retrofit2.HttpException

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue I needed to handle the exception from the Repository as its where the Api gets called initially